# James converted before or after Jesus' resurection appearance?

Tags: john, jesus, acts, 1-corinthians, james-apostle

In John 7:3-5 (NASB)

> 3 So His brothers said to Him, “Move on from here and go into Judea, so that Your disciples also may see Your works which You are doing. 4 For no one does anything in secret when he himself is striving to be known publicly. If You are doing these things, show Yourself to the world.” 5 **For not even His brothers believed in Him**.

In Acts 1:14 (NASB)

> 14 All these were continually devoting themselves with one mind to prayer, along with the women, and Mary the mother of Jesus, and **with His brothers**.

From John 7 to Acts 1 we see there's a conversion of James, the brother of Jesus.

The question is in regards to 1 Corinthians 15:7 (NASB)

> 7 then **He appeared to James**, then to all the apostles;

was James converted before or after resurected Jesus appeared to him?

Comment: Interestingly as well, in Galatians 1:19 (NASB), «19 But I did not see another one of the apostles except James, the Lord’s brother.».

Comment: We are not told, but that is likely the case.

Comment: @Dottard meaning that resurrected Jesus appeared to someone who wasn't a believer?

Comment: Why not? - Perhaps that is what converted him??

Comment: @Dottard I thought Jesus' appearances were only made to believers

Comment: Do you have any Bible evidence of that?  (I am unaware of any.)  Besides, Jesus, during His time on earth often talked to sinners and people who clearly did not believe him.  What about the Saul before he became Paul on the road to Damascus - an unbeliever indeed!!

Comment: @Dottard well observed and thank you for bringing that up on Saul/Paul! just saw [this article](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Comm/stewart_don/faq/objections-to-the-resurrection-of-jesus-christ/17-did-jesus-only-appear-to-believers-who-were-expecting-a-resurrection.cfm), might be interesting to read through.

Comment: @Dottard do you want to answer then giving that information that we discussed in the comments including the "we're not told"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that James, the brother of Jesus did not believe that Jesus was Messiah of the world -

> John 7:5 - For even His own brothers did not believe in Him.

However, with James at least, that changed because by Acts 15, it appears that James had become one of the leaders of the early church; see Acts 15:13-18, Gal 1:19.  Further, the NT book of James also appears to have been written by Jesus' brother.

We are not told when this change or conversion of James occurred, however, we can reduce the window of time in which it occurred.  By Acts 1;14, James appears to have become a Christian - just 10 days after Jesus' ascension and 50 days after Jesus' resurrection.

Intriguingly, James is specifically mentioned by Paul in 1 Cor 15:7 -

> Then He appeared to James, then to all the apostles.

Assuming this is the same James the brother of Jesus, (as appears very likely) then it may have been this personal appearance to James after the resurrection that finally convinced him.  While speculative (we are not told) it is quite possible that James' conversion took place either then or a few day's later.